# Entity Framework update field from other fields of the same class/model

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

```
public class Person
{
     public string FirstName { get; set; } = string.Empty
     public string LastName { get; set; } = string.Empty
     public string FullName { get; set; } = string.Empty
}
```

How can I update `FullName` as

```
FullName = $"{FirstName} {LastName}"
```

Placing the above line in the constructor doesn't seem to cut it as values of `FirstName` & `LastName` seems to be default and Entity Framework persists as an empty string too.

How can I make this work with EF without explicitly calling a method or assigning directly to the field `FullName` from other classes?

Package: EF Core Cosmos 3.1

Comment: You need to be more clear on when in the lifecycle of the object you want this value to be populated. Perhaps it is easier to describe when the FullName property will be consumed. If FullName is persisted to the database as a column then it makes sense to build this into your add/edit/update routines, if FullName is only needed on the client then there are some serialisation events we can take advantage of. If you dont't need to persist it at all, just make this a readonly property that returns the interpolated string.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to persist the FullName property, you can go with:

```
[NotMapped]
public string FullName => $"{FirstName} {LastName}";
```